# react component not running the cleanup function on unmount. Working with firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component useEffect hook that looks like the following. I am working with firestore. I am trying to remove a value from an array in firestore when the component unmounts. However, the value is not getting removed. I tried running the firestore query in the cleanup function independently to see if that query was the problem, but it's working fine independently. It's just not getting executed when it's inside the cleanup function. I THINK the problem is that my cleanup function at the end of the useEffect hook is not getting called when the component unmounts(for example when I close the window). does anyone know what I may be doing wrong? Thank you for your help in advance

```
   useEffect(() => {
    
    ....... 

    return () => {
        fire.firestore().collection("ActiveUsers").doc(utilvar.teacherID).get().then((snapshot) => {
            var docref = snapshot.ref;
            return docref.update({
                active_users : fieldValue.arrayRemove({id: currentUser.uid, name: displayName})
            })                     
        }) 
    };
    

}, []);
```

Comment: Does your query depends on any state variables which are initiated with a null or empty value? If so, this might be the problem, since the cleanup function is called with the values passed to it when its defined, i.e. on mount.

Answer (score 0):

From my observation. `utilvar.teacherID` might not be ready as at the time your component got mounted.
So you may want to add it to the dependable array.
Your `useEffect` should therefore look something like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    ....... 

    return () => {
        fire.firestore().collection("ActiveUsers").doc(utilvar.teacherID).get().then((snapshot) => {
if(snapshot.exist){
return snapshot.ref.update({
                active_users : fieldValue.arrayRemove({id: currentUser.uid, name: displayName})
            }).catch(err=>err);                    
        }) 
    };
    

}, [utilvar.teacherID]);
```

I added the catch as it a promise being returned. It must be handled appropriately irrespective of where it's being used.